# How to Access Collectin Object data in HTML Using meteor?

Tags: meteor

I need to know about to access Collection object data in html as shown below :

```
var fieldData = [

      {fieldName: "Hcare1",

       fieldOptions: [ "Bike","Car","TV","Radio","etc"]

      },

      {fieldName: "Hcare2",

       fieldOptions: [ "Bike1","Car1","TV1","Radio1","etc"]
       },

     {fieldName: "Hcare3",

       fieldOptions: [ "Bike2","Car2","TV2","Radio2","etc"]
      }

    ];
```

In the above code how to access **fieldOptions** data in html.The fieldData is inserted into a collection i.e Collection name is `Fields`.I'm new to meteor.So can you please suggest me what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mongo console:

```
db.foo.findOne().fieldOptions;
[ "Bike", "Car", "TV", "Radio", "etc" ]
```

Or on client:

```
collectionName.findOne().fieldOptions;
```

In JS:

```
 Template.your_layout.helpers({
   fieldOptions: function() {
    Fields.findOne().fieldOptions;
   }
 });
```

In HTML:

```
{{#each fieldOptions}}
  {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

Smth like this...

Comment: Yeah,But Its return like as a string means it displays bike,car,tv,radio,etc like this but i need to get like as array means one by one access.@none

Comment: Try this in HTML: 
`{{#each array}}
  {{@index}}: {{this}}
{{/each}}`

Comment: Can you please edit your posted code with get exact output means returns one by one fieldoptions data.I didn't get any out put to exexute above one.So please suggest me?.@none

Comment: @none Please, note that the handlebars' `@index` helper is not supported in meteor.